# Drake problems with import name 'MultidbodyPlant'

Tags: drake

I can't import name 'MultidbodyPlant' from pydrake.all:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MultidbodyPlant' from 'pydrake.all' (/home/dmitriy/git/drake-build/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/all.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct spelling is `MultibodyPlant` not `MultidbodyPlant`.

Comment: thanks, it is a error in code so.